# Errores de linkeado en C++

Tags: c++

Hola estoy intentando compilar mi proyecto usando una librería adicional primero genero el código compilado de mi programa:

```
gcc -o programa.exe Dynamic.cpp
```

Después le añado la librería a mi programa:

```
g++ -o programa.exe Dynamic.o hook.o
```

Pero me muestra los siguientes errores:

```
hook.o:hook.c:(.text+0xa2c): undefined reference to `InitializeBuffer'
hook.o:hook.c:(.text+0xa7d): undefined reference to `UninitializeBuffer'
hook.o:hook.c:(.text+0xb14): undefined reference to `IsExecutableAddress'
hook.o:hook.c:(.text+0xb27): undefined reference to `IsExecutableAddress'
hook.o:hook.c:(.text+0xb52): undefined reference to `AllocateBuffer'
hook.o:hook.c:(.text+0xb7c): undefined reference to `CreateTrampolineFunction'
hook.o:hook.c:(.text+0xca0): undefined reference to `FreeBuffer'
hook.o:hook.c:(.text+0xd82): undefined reference to `FreeBuffer'
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../mingw
32/bin/ld.exe: hook.o: bad reloc address 0x13c in section `.rdata'
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../mingw
32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Para solucionarlo necesito linkear a la libreria buffer como muestro en la captura intento hacer siguiendo los pasos indicados pero no funcionó:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recomiendo usar msys o cmake ya que la versión de codeblocks es un poco antigua o actualizarla a una nueva versión.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que es C++? Has etiquetado la pregunta como [tag:C].

Comment: Ya lo corregi puse c++ aunque la librería esta en c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la librería no se encuentra en la ruta por defecto del compilador tienes que indicar la ruta de forma explícita para que el compilador sepa encontrarla:

Opcion 1:

```
g++ -o ... -L[ruta_libreria]/[nombre_libreria]
```

Opcion 2:

```
g++ -o ... -L[ruta_libreria] -l[nombre_libreria]
```

En cuanto a qué librerías te hacen falta... deberías revisar la lista de dependencias de tus fuentes y librerías estáticas. En eso no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Al final funciono pongo toda mi solucion son las librerias hay que incluirlas todas y poner los .a.

Comment: @OmarOmar No te puse la extensión porque en Windows suele ser .lib y podría crear confusión. Los compiladores de C++ no entienden de extensiones de ficheros y por eso hay que indicar **el nombre completo**

Answer (score 0):

Instale `msys` que incluye una colección de todas `las dependencias necesaria`s. Suplementa a `las deficiencias en consola` (ya que `Mingw` usa una versión anticuada (`TDM-GCC 4.9.2 SJLJ (released in October 30, 2014)`) y supongo que no la incluirá por defecto.

Para resolverlo hice:

```
g++ -o bot.exe Dynamic.o hook.o -L/c/"ruta"/ trampoline.a buffer.a hde32.a
```